# User feed URL text has insufficient contrast

Tags: bug, design, feed, accessibility

I tried the *User feed* link in the profile page (leading to `<site>/feeds/user/<userid>`) and I think the background shouldn't be greyed out because if you unselect the URL its text becomes hard to read against the background.

[image: user feed dialogue]

The dialogue can be compared to the usual *Share* *(a link to)* dialogue under each post that doesn't have the background greyed out.

[image: share link dialogue]